# Quantum mechanics with non-holonomic constraints?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

Are there any established theories for non-holonomic quantum mechanics? I have googled for d'Alembert's principle, non-holonomic constraints and quantum mechanics but only found an abstract talking about golden nanocars so would like to know if there had been any progress.

Comment: Interesting question, but it's not clear to me what would even be meant by nonholonomic quantum mechanics. What would it even mean, quantum-mechanically, to constrain an electron's velocity without constraining its position? If we constrain its velocity, then doesn't its uncertainty in position become infinite by the uncertainty principle?

Comment: Ben: perhaps it can be constrained probabilistically or something? Hope someone has insight.

Comment: The whole point of setting forth Hamiltonians at a classical level is to get rid of constraints and fictitious forces which pop-up in the Newtonian approach. I cannot see the relevance of this in quantization.

Comment: As I understand it Hamiltonians cannot describe physics with nonholonomic constraints, so it should be relevant?

Comment: I might be answering to the void here, but I just ran into this thread and wanted to pass along a reference to an article I co-wrote with a chemist on precisely this topic (quantum nonholonomic mechanics): https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-33023-8.

Comment: @OscarFernandez Not the void. Particle number is at least one here. I find it quite cool, actually. I will try to read the paper in detail.